# Runtime error sorting a linked list of strings

Tags: c, string, sorting, linked-list

```
void sort(struct node **s2) {
    struct node *x, *y;
    x = *s2;
    char *str;
    while (x != NULL) {
        y = x->n;
        while (y != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(x->name, y->name) > 0) {
                strcpy(str, x->name);
                strcpy(x->name, y->name);
                strcpy(y->name, str);
            }
            y = y->n;
        }
        x = x->n;
    }
}
```

This is showing a run time error.
I don't know whats wrong
I believe the sorting is correct
It's selection sort
The structure of my node is:

```
struct node {
    char *name;
    struct node *n;
};
```

It's showing runtime error.

Comment: Your sort function does not compile, you're missing a `}`

Comment: oh i m sorry i missed out a } here...i have all the } in my original program

Comment: Your algorithm is an unstable variant of selection sort.  Its time-complexity is  **O(N^2)**.  Try and implement merge sort, a much more efficient algorithm with worst-case time-complexity of **O(N.log(N))**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`char *str; ... strcpy(str,x->name);` copies data pointed to by `name` to an *someplace* (it is undefined behavior) as `str` is an uninitialized pointer.

Just swap pointers.

```
       if (strcmp(x->name,y->name) > 0) {
         char *temp = x->name;
         x->name = y->name;
         y->name = temp;
       }
```

Comment: thanks ,swapping the pointers  works but I'm confused-what is wrong with swapping the data?.

Comment: Three reasons: any string might not have the space to store a longer string; and you have not allocated any memory to your scratch space `*str`; and execution time.

Comment: got it.Thank's a lot

Answer (score 1):

`char *str;` 
This statement only create a pointer. There is no memory is associated with that;

`strcpy(char* dest, char* src)` simply copies the the content in the memory pointed by **src** to memory point by **dest**

In your case **str not pointing to any memory location**;

`strcpy(str, x->name)`

since **str pointing to nothing**, this statement endup with an error because strcpy fails to copy to str

instead of `char* str;` 
use `char str[SIZE_MAX];`

Comment: I'm afraid `char str[SIZE_MAX];` is not an option because `SIZE_MAX`, the maximum value of type `size_t`, is much too large, likely larger than available memory and definitely too much for an automatic variable.